# What would cause a sharepoint publishing page to display a "Lorem ipsum"?

Tags: publishing, error

I've created a publishing page, placed a custom web part on in and published it. When I try to navigate to it I see this text instead of the content:

> Page Content field value. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Searching the web I've found similar pages, for example: https://www.mundaring.wa.gov.au/ResidentServices/PublicHealth/Pages/default.aspx?ID=4&ID=4

One thing about the page is that it's getting a query parameter called `id` - could that be causing the error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say yes, it's certainly the query string parameter you are using. Check out this post for more details http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/01/30/querystring-parameters-you-should-not-use-in-your-sharepoint-application.aspx

Comment: +1 for more information available on this link.

Comment: lol that sure is weird behaviour. Nice find

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is the issue - I've sent the system admin the updated solution even before writing the question, but though I'd ask anyway. I'll update soon. In my defense, I should state that **it worked on my machine**, but not on the test environment.

Comment: Important update - Our system guy is sick, so you won't get those 15 points for now, but you've got your health!

Answer (score 2):

Can you please recheck with giving `id=1`?

While passing ID as query string it's going to cast ID in some numeric format, so it will cause issues.

It's loading contents from the SiteLibrary pages document library.

Answer (score 1):

For the cases when you want to use your custom web part inside of a SharePoint 2013 page, I can suggest you the following workaround:

- download web part page from SharePoint 2010
- upload it in SharePoint 2013 using the explorer view
- add your web part that uses the reserved url parameters

In my case this worked. Here is a blog post I have written: http://spobject.blogspot.com/2014/03/page-content-field-value-lorem-ipsum.html