# How can I change the URL of my intranet so it's just the company name?

Tags: 2010, url, web

I was wondering if it was possible to change the way a sharepoint 2010 URL displays.  For example, if the real URL is, "http://intranet.myco.org/sites/intranet/default.aspx", can this be changed to display and to go to "http://intranet.myco.org"?  Our users find the long URLs difficult.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Those are fundamentally 2 different places.

- http://intranet.myco.org is a root web application/site collection.
- http://intranet.myco.org/sites/intranet/default.aspx is a separate site collection under a managed path of a web application.

If you want people to go to the root URL, then provision a site collection in that web application and they can just go there directly.

Comment: Alternatively, keep the site provisioned where it is, and assuming there is nothing in the http://intranet.myco.org, provision a site collection there and just use a redirect to redirect the user to the /sites/intranet site collection.  I'd probably just do a site collection backup/restore and place the /sites/intranet into the root site collection of the web application, like PirateEric suggests.

Comment: By the way, if you don't have a Site Collection provisioned in the Web Application root, certain client functionality (for example from Office Clients) may not work as expected.  I ran into this with InfoPath: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/d9a885eb-face-4aab-8ba9-368a95ffe342

Answer (score 0):

Go to Central Admin->Application Management-->Configure Alternate Access Mapping

Click On Add Internal Urls--> Add ur new host name and port number selecting your webapplication. Also Select your zone.

Save it there and go to your IIS and select your web application and set the bindings to new host name(www.intranet.myco.org). Include your port number and save that.

Add host record in your DNS Server.

That should work.

Comment: It appears he has already done so, and is asking about URL Rewriting, not Alternate Access Mapping

Comment: You could use the Alternate Access mappings if, for example, you had the site collection provisioned at the web application root (i.e. http://intranet.myco.org) and wanted to simply access it via http://intranet.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following link for information on URL Rewriting...

[Support for URL rewriting?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12702/support-for-url-rewriting)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, look at using Host Named Site Collections.  Here is a starting point: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx