# How to convert the SharePoint requests to Lowercase in the IIS processing pipe line

Tags: iis, url, iis7

Wants to convert the SharePoint requests to Lowercase in the IIS processing pipe line, it should not invoke additional request to change/convert the requested URL into lowercase but the same request should be converted.

The below IIS Rewrite Rule converts the URL which needs an  additional request:

< rules>
< rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="false">
< match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false"/>
< conditions>
< add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="*lb-live.aspx$"/>
< /conditions>
< action type="redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
< /rule>

Is there a way to simply convert the case while the request is being processed in IIS pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requirement is very specific to your project. You can fulfil it by writing a HTTP Module which intercepts every SharePoint request, and converts it to Lowercase, see below:

```
public void Init(System.Web.HttpApplication Appl)
        {
            //Hookup the function that does the lowercase
            Appl.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Appl_BeginRequest);
        }

void Appl_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.HttpApplication myAppl = (System.Web.HttpApplication)sender;
            string requestUrl = myAppl.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToLower();

            //additional checks on url
            if (requestUrl.Contains("test"))
            {

            }
        }
```

For addtional help, please see this link: [Support for URL rewriting?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12702/support-for-url-rewriting)

Comment: Is that mean that we can simply change the case while the request is in the IIS pipeline?...have gone through many articles however seems that we can only change and place a new request using the  "Rewrite" method...?

Comment: Every request goes through Application_BeginRequest anyway. You'll need to add some logic there. see my updated response.

Comment: thanks for the code sample. Simply wants to convert the case on the IIS Request pipeline, how Could I achieve this without a redirection or placing another request...

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible without placing an another request.