# different urls for site collections within same web application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am using SharePointe 2010, and newbie with sharepoint. I am trying to create site collections by using powershell and c#. my client wants to have different urls for each site collection within same web application 
something like (sc1.domain.com, sc2.domain.com ....) is it possible? thanks

Comment: I have tried using managed path, by using powershell like this: New-SPSite -Url $url -OwnerAlias $domainAnduser -Name $name -Template $template

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12702/support-for-url-rewriting I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you're after (unique FQDN for each site collection in the same web application) in a supported manner you'll need to use host-named site collections ([Plan for host-named site collections (SharePoint 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx)). In addition to the TechNet documentation, another great primer can be found at [What Every SharePoint Admin Needs to Know About Host Named Site Collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/03/27/what-every-sharepoint-admin-needs-to-know-about-host-named-site-collections.aspx).

Comment: Hi and thanks, I succeeded to created site collections with thier own content database. But now the problem is when I browse to them I have to log in.