# Auto forward to another Site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, redirect

I have created a root site collection with following url:

```
 http://sp.domain.com
```

I want to auto redirect all users who browse to the root site collection to another site collection with this url:

```
  http://sp.domain.com/sites/firstSite
```

so that nobody can use root site collection. What can be the best solution.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1):

Add content editor webpart on your root site collection ,  http://sp.domain.com and put below javascript in that webpart

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.location = "http://sp.domain.com/sites/firstSite"
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested your answer. It is right but for a short time users see the root site collection. I would like to redirect the users before they come to the first page of the root site collection. right now I am trying to write a http module but the disadvanteges of http module is they must be registered by editing web.config file. I tested URL-Rewrite which is created by this guy, but no success yet. http://blog.mastykarz.nl/friendly-urls-sharepoint-site-4-steps-iis7-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: for rewriting the url plese refer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12702/support-for-url-rewriting

Comment: for writing a http module, this should help you : http://www.thedotnotcorner.com/2012/06/07/sharepoint-2010-url-redirection-rewriting-using-httpmodule-for-anonymous-web-application/